# Jquery autocomplete is not showing any autocomplete list in spring forms

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am having a input field on which I want to enable autocomplete feature. I have included below in the header section.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Field

```
<form:input path="customer" maxlength="50" id="customer"
placeholder="Customer Name" cssClass="form-control"
required="true" />
```

Js

```
$( "#customer" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "http://localhost:8888/rider/get_rider",
                    dataType : "json",
                    method:'GET',
                    data : {
                        term : request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        response(data.map(function(value){
                            console.log(value);
                            return {
                                label: value.name,
                                value: value.name,
                                description: value.name
                            };
                        }));

                    }
                });
                }

        });
```

I can see that a valid json response is sent back from the controller.

Controller

```
@GetMapping(value="/get_rider",produces = "application/json")
    public List<RiderGroupDTO> getCustomerName(@RequestParam("term") String query){
        List<RiderGroupDTO> li=new ArrayList<>();
        li=riderGroupService.findAllGroups();

        return li;
    }
```

Response

```
{id: 1, name: "Admin", description: "Admin group to send coupons to all "}
{id: 2, name: "food", description: "food coupons"}
```

The issue is that, though the response is getting sent , it is not getting shown on the jsp. Even there is no error on browser console. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Check in network what response you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to test on a local server.  This seems to work as far as getting JSON back from the php page.  I think one problem might have been with the JSON that you are returning.  I was not getting JSON back.  I am not sure how the autocomplete works really, so you might have to play around with that because it is just displaying all "name" values and not filtering by what I type in.

This is what I have an a server.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input path="customer" maxlength="50" id="customer" placeholder="Customer Name" cssClass="form-control" required="true" />

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#customer" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "test1.php",
                    dataType : "json",
                    method:'POST',
                    data : {},
                    success: function(data){
                        response(data.map(function(value){
                            console.log(value);
                            return {
                                label: value.name,
                                value: value.name,
                                description: value.name
                            };
                        }));

                    }
                });
                }

        });
});
</script>
```

JSON response, really an array of objects, and I think you need the quotes around the name/value pairs.

```
[{"id": "1", "name": "Admin", "description": "Admin group to send coupons to all"},
{"id": "2", "name": "food", "description": "food coupons"}]
```

[image: Example]

Comment: You must actually return the filtered results from the .php page based on a database query for LIKE or something.  If that is the case, seems to work actually.

Comment: I paste a picture.  That is why I am assuming that you do the filtering server side.  I actually use SumoSelect, which does the filtering client side, but I guess doing it server side has some advantages.

Comment: You might want to use a more recent version of Jquery UI, also, like 1.12.1.  There might be a bug on other issue with the 1.8.18 version.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!  The issue was indeed related to jquery version. I replaced the existing one with jquery 1.12.1 and things are working perfectly now.